# jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate not inserting rows

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to do a batch insert, but when run in Tomcat the app seems to hang, and no new rows inserted. Below is my code:

```
public class MatchDAOImpl implements MatchDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public MatchDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void batchInsert(final List<Match> matches){

        String sql = "INSERT INTO matches (id, status, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_goals, away_goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                Match match = matches.get(i);
                System.out.println("Inserting values for #" + match.getId());
                ps.setInt(1, match.getId());
                ps.setString(2, match.getStatus());
                ps.setInt(3, match.getHomeTeam().getId());
                ps.setInt(4, match.getAwayTeam().getId());
                ps.setInt(5, match.getHomeGoals());
                ps.setInt(6, match.getAwayGoals());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return matches.size();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is an example of it being called:

```
matchesDAO.batchInsert(matches);
```

Also, you'll see I have a println command so I know that it's at least using this method. Below is a sample output from this:

```
Inserting values for #233398
Inserting values for #233399
Inserting values for #233400
Inserting values for #233401
Inserting values for #233402
...
```

However, when I check the database for any new rows there are none (empty table). I'm not getting any exception thrown to indicate what the issue is. Does my method look OK?

UPDATE

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.budget")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    //...

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
//      dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName( OracleDriver.class.getName() );
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        dataSource.setUsername("budget_admin");
        dataSource.setPassword("budg3t");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public MatchDAO getMatchDAO() {
        return new MatchDAOImpl(getDataSource());
    }
```

Here is where batchInsert is being called for now:

```
@Controller
public class MatchesController {

    @Autowired
    private FootballData footballData;

    @Autowired 
    private MatchDAO matchDAOImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/matches")
    public ModelAndView matches(ModelAndView model) {

        List<Match> matches = footballData.requestMatches();

        // write to db
        matchDAOImpl.batchInsert(matches);

        model.addObject("matches", matches);
        model.setViewName("matches");

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a transaction wrapping all of this, and being committed at some point?

Comment: No I don't think so. I've been following along this tutorial - https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/

Comment: Can you share your datasource JDBC URL with us ?

Comment: And also, how do you execute the `batchInsert` method ? From a `main`, web controller? Perhaps from a `JUnit` test ? We need to know, whether there is perhaps an enclosing transaction.

Comment: I've updated my original post now as to where/how I'm calling the batchInsert.

Comment: Read the Spring documentation. You need a DataSourceTransactionManager, and your DAO method at least, or your controller method calling it, must be transactional.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I'll check that out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us if it helped?  I vaguelly remember,  that oracle autocommit is a bit different to MySQL. I wonder, where the real problem was. This example would insert data to MySQL just fine,  right?